# issue with Helium spell with Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin, helium

I am trying to verfiy Helium integration with zeppelin , I am able to verfiy the Visulization part, like using zeppelin-highcharts-bubble example, this is working, so I tried to check the **spell** part for that I tried to do the below steps

```
$cd  zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all/local-repo/vis/node_modules/
$npm -i zeppelin-echo-spell
$cp zeppelin-echo-spell.json ~/zeppelin-0.7.0-bin-all/helium
```

step: edited the artifact id to zeppelin-echo-spell@1.0.7

next step:went to /helium and enabled the zeppelin-echo-spell

[image]

next step: went to notepad and run %echo but getting the below error

```
paragraph_1505902200429_-2022864217's Interpreter echo not found
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, spell only works for 0.8.0+